# Google .NET API - How to use ExecuteAsStream

Tags: .net, stream, google-api, blogger, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm creating a Windows WPF app that downloads and saves Blogger posts using the Google Blogger API v3.  The `Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest<TResponse>`, which I believe is common amongst the various API libraries, defines a few methods for retrieving data including, Execute, and ExecuteAsStream. Since my app could be downloading hundreds of blogs (if the user doesn't narrow by a date range), I thought it might be a good idea to download the posts as a stream and process one post at a time rather than download all posts into memory at once. Is that how ExecuteAsStream even works? The problem is I don't know how to handle the Stream. I can read x bytes at a time, but how do I know when I've read 1 full post and how do I convert it to a Post object? Here is some of my code with the ExecuteAsStream call commented.

```
BloggerService blogger = new BloggerService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApplicationName = "BloggerHelper", HttpClientInitializer = credential });

var blogRequest = blogger.Blogs.GetByUrl(blogUrl);
Blog blog = blogRequest.Execute();

string id = blog.Id;

var postRequest = blogger.Posts.List(id);
PostList posts = await postRequest.ExecuteAsync(cancelToken);
//using (Stream postStream = await postRequest.ExecuteAsStreamAsync(cancelToken))
//{
    //Iterate Posts and save each post to a file
```

Comment: I would suggest that you look at the stream being returned.. i.e. just output the data as a string in debugger or file (or use fiddler) etc.. and it might give you some clue.. like it may be serialized as Json or XML etc..